# VBS запустить из скрипта программу,в определенный час

Tags: vbscript

```
On Error Resume Next  NameScript = WScript.ScriptFullName  With WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") Dim wsh: Set wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") wsh.Run("""c:\zipper\zip3.exe""") RegScript = .RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\MyScript") AddReg = True  If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Clear  ElseIf RegScript = NameScript Then  AddReg = False  End If  If AddReg Then  .RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\MyScript", NameScript, "REG_SZ"  .Run "%systemroot%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters", 0, True  End If  End With
```

Есть вот такой скрипт, он сам себя добавил в автозагрузку и при включении компьютера, запускает программу. Мне бы хотелось чтоб этот скрипт висел в памяти, и в определенный час - например в 12:00 запускал бы программу zip3. Как запустить в определенный день видел, а в час нет. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Сделал сам, если кому интересно будет выкладываю код, может и не красиво но работает

Comment: On Error Resume Next 
NameScript = WScript.ScriptFullName 
With WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox hour(now) 
MsgBox minute(now) 
Set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
do 
'код 
if hour(now) = 19 And minute(now) = 27 And second(now) = 00  Then
Dim wsh: Set wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run("""c:\zipper\zip3.exe""")
End if
'код 
loop

Comment: RegScript = .RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\MyScript") 
AddReg = True 
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
Err.Clear 
ElseIf RegScript = NameScript Then 
AddReg = False 
End If 
If AddReg Then 
.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\MyScript", NameScript, "REG_SZ" 
.Run "%systemroot%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters", 0, True 
End If 
End With